# nth-child selector based on CSS var number

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-variables

I am trying to achieve something like this

```css
:root {
  --grid-columns: 6; /* default number of columns */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  :root {
    --grid-columns: 8; /* adjust number of columns for desktop */
  }
}

.grid-item:nth-child( var(--grid-columns)n + 1) ) {
  /* styles for first item in each row */
}
```

Is this somehow possible with pure CSS?

Comment: don't think this is possible with pure css